# Importing nodejs `fs` with typescript when executing with ts-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.2, ts-node

I'm trying to run the following code with [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node).

```
import { writeFileSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
```

However I get:

```
src/main/ts/create.ts (1,45): Cannot find module 'fs'. (2307)
```

What do I need to do in to allow typescript to import the fs module?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to run:

```
$ npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

If you need additional information you can refer to the [NodeJS QuickStart in the TypeScript Deep Dive by Basarat](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/nodejs.html).